Как привязать данные из колонок одной таблицы в разные comboBox?
Привязка колонки мастер привязывается. Все показывает.
    
<ComboBox x:Name="textBoxMaster" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ToolTip="Мастер" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="Master_SelectionChanged"
SelectedItem ="{Binding Path = MastSchedule.Master}"/>

Теперь надо привязать к другому comboBox из этой же таблице колонку Time
<ComboBox x:Name="textBoxTime" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
ToolTip="Время визита" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Height="30"                 
Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="textBoxTime_SelectionChanged" />

Вот сама таблица
public class MastSchedule
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Master { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time{ get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString() => Master;
}


У вас нет здесь привязок к коллекции вообще. Привязка элементов комбобокса выполняется через ItemsSource. Отображаемый элемент определяется через DisplayMemberPath. Только вы говорите про какую-то колонку, показывая просто класс. А где коллекция - неизвестно.

textBoxMaster.ItemsSource = App.Db.MastSchedules.ToList(); Да, вот эта привязка к колонке мастер. И мне надо привязать колонку TIME из этой же таблицы к другому комбобоксу

Это не привязка, это вы просто копируете данные из модели в UI. У одной DisplayMemberPath="Master" у второй DisplayMemberPath="Time", а ItemsSource одинаковый. SelectedItem уберите, вы по ходу не поняли, зачем оно нужно. Первый комбо у вас работает, потому что отображает через public override string ToString().

@aepot Спасибо огромное! Все получилось!

Это делается через DisplayMemberPath
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Master" ... />

<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Time" ... />

При этом ItemsSource у обоих комбобоксов должен быть одинаковый.
